# Particle System water ripple effect not visible in final render. why?

Tags: rendering, animation, particles, system

I made a lave animation effect by using a particle system with a lava plane as canvas and another invisible plane as emitter brush which emits cube to impact with the canvas plane and animate the canvas plane.

[image]

The effect is quite what I wanted if you check the video link below.

[Animated lava video pre render](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=9901043736FBFBA5&id=9901043736FBFBA5%2117245&parId=9901043736FBFBA5%21127&o=OneUp)

However, when I do the final render the lava plane does not animate at all and I cannot find out why?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: did you bake the dynamics?

Comment: No I did not since I am using evee as my render engine.

Comment: bake the Physics Simulations https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/baking.html, then render the animation.

Comment: Once baked the animation rendered.  Thanks.  Though I could not bake it since I was working with evee and the baking options are only available in cycles but I switched engines to bake and it worked in evee as well